# How to get data from AJAX and show/hide div accordingly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, get

I'm writing a PHP script that echoes a number which represents the amount of unread messages.

I have the following code which processes the PHP every 30 seconds.

```
setInterval(function (){
            $.ajax({
                url: "php/notifications_counter.php",
                cache: false,
                success: function(number){
                $("#notification_counter").show();
                $("#notification_counter_number").text(number);
      }
    });
        },5010);
```

The number that the PHP echoes should be inserted into the div called '#notification_counter_number'. And indeed the number gets inserted. But for some strange reason, together with the number also the commenting inside the php file gets echoed? I can't get this to work properly.

Additionally, I want the #notification_counter to show when there is a number echoed, but hidden when there is none. So i tried the following code for that:

```
...success: function(number){
                if (number > 0) {
                  $("#notification_counter").show();
                  $("#notification_counter_number").text(number);}
                else {$("#notification_counter").show();}
  }
```

This doesn't work either:( The div always gets hidden, even if PHP outputs a number more than 0. Hope you guys can help.

UPDATE: this is my php file:

```
<!--
blabla commenting, so this gets visible as text in DIV as well. Strange...

!-->

    <?php

    include "config.php";

    //Count unread messages from database
    $Number_Query = mysqli_query ($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE Notification_Read='0' "); 

    $Notification_Count = mysqli_num_rows($Number_Query);

    if ($Notification_Count > 0) {
    echo "$Notification_Count"; }

    //Close connection
    mysqli_close($mysqli);

    ?>
```

Comment: We need to see notifications_counter.php

Comment: BTW: Don't use `setInterval`, use `setTimeout` instead

Comment: Can we see how you are doing the commenting in your php file? The only way it would show is if its actually echoed to the page...in theory. What do you see on the page if you just hit the `php/notifications_counter.php` url directly?

Comment: PHP file added. However i'm sure that it works correctly. The number gets outputted to the page but the problem is that the comments also get outputted...

Comment: http://a-training.nl/sotwebapp/php/notifications_counter.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<!-- -->` is an HTML comment, that is output to the browser, simply change to php comments:

```
<?php
/*
blabla commenting, so this gets visible as text in DIV as well. Strange...

*/

include "config.php";
```

Whilst you are making changes, it would also make sense to output JSON, which would allow you to add extra data if needed (eg comment times, author etc):

```
$Notification_Count = mysqli_num_rows($Number_Query);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('count'=>$Notification_Count));


//javascript
success: function(data){
   if (data.count > 0)...
```

Answer (score 1):

So when you get a page via ajax its going to return the entire body, not just what you can see in a browser. so the `<!--` html comment is being returned in the string. You need to remove that output altogether by using php comments or your calculation of `number > 0` will fail.

If you absolutely can't change the PHP output for whatever reason you can strip the response of all characters by doing something like:

`if (number.replace(/\D/g,'') > 0) {`

but that's pretty gross. better to clean up your php file.

Comment: This will still fail as his javascript expects a number and performs a calculation on it `if(number > 0)...`